# 500 server internal error in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, axios

I'm having error when I update this.

**app.js**

```
  approveleave() {
    var idapprove = document.getElementById("leave_id").value;
     alert(idapprove);
    axios.post('/approveleave/' + idapprove)
      .then(response => {
      this.showModal=false;
      this.getleaveItems(); //view list
      });
      // this.leave = true;
      this.update = true;
  },
```

**controller.php**

```
public function requestApproveLeave(Request $request, $id){
 $leavedata = LeaveRequest::where('leave_id', $id);

  if($leavedata->head == 'pending' ){
    $leavedata->head = 'approved';
    // $data->hr = 'approved';
    $leavedata->save();
    return $leavedata;
  }else{
  return $leavedata;
  } 
}  

public function requestLeave(){

  $leaveIds = DB::select('SELECT * FROM leave_requests lr INNER JOIN users u ON lr.user_id = u.id');

  return  $leaveIds;

}
```

I have a button in the `view.blade.php` that updates to approve. What happens is that when I click and check in the console, there's `500 server internal error`. My routes, controller and `getleaveItems` work fine.

Comment: What exception do you see in the Laravel logs?

Comment: @piscator . I add this.  .catch(response => {
            alert(response.data);
          }); .it says undefined.. I don't know how to use laravel logs..

Comment: They are located in the `storage/logs` folder. Here you can find the 500 internal server error exception. After you find the exception, you can add it to your question.

Comment: laravel.logs is too big.. quite confused

Comment: @piscator i think this one.                                                                                            Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `leave_requests` set `updated_at` = 2018-08-17 09:35:36, `head` = 2 where `id` is null)

Comment: Nice, you've found the problem :). The `$id` parameter in `requestApproveLeave` is null. This either means `idapprove` in your js is also null, or there is something wrong with your route definition. After you've solved this, make sure to check the value `$id` in your method, and return an error message when the value is null.

Comment: @piscator .there's an alert above the axios.post. And I recieve the ID which is 2. So by that. I can change the leave->head = 'approved'. Is there any other way to return the value from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you controller your have

```
$leavedata = LeaveRequest::where('leave_id', $id);
```

at this point $leavedata is just an instance of the Query Builder therefore any code below that point that tries to access retrieved models properties will fail

Based on your current setup you should add firstOrFail() at the end.

```
$leavedata = LeaveRequest::where('leave_id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

So in case of the record not being found the method would safely abort and return a 404 error.

Comment: .On my tutorial i;ve copied he do  this. $leavedata = LeaveRequest::where('leave_id', $id)->first(); I wonder if thats the same

Comment: @chimichi004 if you decide to use first() then after that you should check if $leaveData is null and then proceed.

Comment: I just want to know if my axios is correct and route. Does my return $leaveIds; is the correct way to return the data?

Comment: I just want you to check in my controller on function requestLeave() because after i edit that. My controller in requestApproveLeave doesnt work. because of that inner join.

Comment: @chimichi004 I dont see anything wrong with your axios. As for the requestLeave() function that returns $leaveIds i am not sure. from your query i assume that 'leave_requests` table has a user_id field that is nullable and you do the inner join to return only ids that have an associated user. So you could just do $leaveRequestsHavingUser = LeaveRequest::has('user')->get(); if you have defined a user relation inside LeaveRequest Model. And if you need only the ids then return just that by using pluck('id') method on the result or add select('id') on the initial query

Comment: well with regards about the requestLeave function. Use it to view all info from the LeaveRequest database to join in Users database. Which is i use to view  in v-for all at once.that y in v-for="leavedetail in leavedetails"

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `leave_requests` set `updated_at` = 2018-08-18 18:01:26, `head` = approved where `id` is null) I'm having issue with this.

Comment: and look at this. {"userId":2,"email":"gula@gmail.com","exception":" .That userId changed the value from my leave_id. that user id should be 3, not 2 coz that's the value of my leave_id in the leave_request table

Comment: Unknown column 'id' means that your table does not have a column Id. I can't tell more without the code of your controller doing the update and the migration class of your leave_requests table